# Change Display Mode of SharePoint Page based on edit Control Panel

Tags: web, web-part

I have a custom web part which shows a different interface when in edit mode.

When in edit mode the default control panel displays on the right.  When the user clicks OK, Cancel or Apply the web part stays in edit mode.

I want the custom web part to leave edit mode when the user selects OK or Cancel in the control panel.

Currently in the CreateChildControls method of the part I check the mode of the page by

```
            bool editMode = false;

            WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);
            if (wpm.SelectedWebPart != null) {
                string selectedId = wpm.SelectedWebPart.ID;
                string thisId = this.ID;
                if (thisId.Equals(selectedId)) {
                    editMode = true;
                }
            }
```

After the user clicks OK or Cancel the editMode remains true.

Ideas? (thx)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the WebPart.BrowserDesignMode Property to check whether the Web Part is in design mode and accordingly switch the display a different interface.

Read more here..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.browserdesignmode.aspx

Comment: Since the WebPart.BrowserDesignMode Property is now obsolete, you can make use of the   
WebPartManager.DisplayMode property to achieve the same goal. 

Read more here..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-
us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpartmanager.displaymode.aspx

Comment: Well, the problem is clicking ok/cancel in the edit control panel does not take my part out of edit mode.

Currently using
                bool editMode = false;
                bool thisPart = false;

                WebPartManager wpm = WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);
                if (wpm.SelectedWebPart != null) {
                    string selectedId = wpm.SelectedWebPart.ID;
                    string thisId = this.ID;
                    if (thisId.Equals(selectedId)) {
                        thisPart = true;
                    }
                }